# while creating a VM which uses DPDK in Ubuntu with machine type as Q35 - I enabled EAL logs, this is the error

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, dpdk

EAL: eal_parse_sysfs_value(): cannot open sysfs value /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/uio/uio0/portio/port0/start
EAL: pci_uio_ioport_map(): cannot parse portio start
EAL: Requested device 0000:02:00.0 cannot be used

Not able to find exact reason!!

It works well with i440fx machine type, but when I choose Q35 machine this is the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SaiNiranjanBN can you please clarify the following, 1) what is host machine, 2) what is host device, 3) are you doing PCIe pass through, 4) what is bios and kernel cmdline setting for iommu, 5) assuming you are enabling vfio-pci on host before starting VM with the device, 6) what exactly is logs for running dpdk with `--log-level=8`, 7) can you access the device without dpdk with machine type Q35 in VM settings?

Comment: Root permission is required to access Physical address and huge pages. So try please